# How to allow users to select all currencies, but with limited languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a Rails i18n app with ~5 languages (English, Spanish, German etc).

The user can already choose between the ~5 languages, but the currency is limited to his language.

I want to allow the users to also choose whatever currency symbol exists out there.

**Example:**

They should be able to use the English language, but the EURO as their currency symbol etc.
A user in South America could select Spanish as a language, but choose whatever currency he needs, since they don't use the Euro.

What is the best way to do this?

Currently we do this to print currency:

```rb
number_to_currency(12345, locale: @company.locale)
```

I am thinking if we should change it to this:

```rb
number_to_currency(12345, locale: @company.currency)
```

We could load the currency in a select box with this helper:

```rb
def locale_currency
  I18n.available_locales.map do |locale|
    [ I18n.t('number.currency.format.unit', locale: locale), locale.to_s ]
  end
end
```

But this helper only shows the symbol, and we see the `$` sign multiple times. It would be better to show the country name, but the country name **is not included** in the translation file:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/da.yml

If the country name was in the file, I could have fetched it with the 
`I18n.t('name')` or similar.

I tried using the [Money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem, but then I would lose the localization feature, and would need to replace the `number_to_currency` everywhere.

Am I on the wrong track? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you be overthinking this?  It would be much easier to just have a translation file which lists the currencies instead of trying to link currencies to locales since the relationship is not exactly straight forward. I'm guessing your not going to have more than a handful of currencies?

Comment: What if I want the app to be able to work in almost every country possible? So they can select their currency, but only between 5 languages.

Comment: Yeah but the link between a locale, a country and a currency is not always that clear cut. Like for example the Dutch Antilles.

Comment: Exactly, and same for the Spanish speaking nations in South America. That is why we want to allow users to select Spanish as a language, and whatever currency is needed.

Comment: I think we mean the same thing here but I'm saying you should create a separate hash where you can lookup currencies by abbreviation instead of trying to find them in hashes organized by locale.

Comment: Does that mean we would have to create that hash with 100+ currencies?
Are we doing something no one is doing? I thought this was straight forward but I cannot find anything about this. We simply want a <select> with all the currencies available.